# reverse geocode using osm2pgsql

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osm.pbf

Hello I have followed this tutorial

https://www.compose.com/articles/geofile-using-openstreetmap-data-in-compose-postgresql-2/

and Implemented database correctly.
 I am looking for a query in which I give lat and long and it gives me the full address. At the moment this query works very well

```
SELECT * FROM planet_osm_point WHERE amenity = 'restaurant'
```

Comment: This is only possible with a real [geocoder](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) such as Nominatim or Photon.

Comment: @scai you don't understand. I am just looking for a query

Comment: I understood. However addresses in OSM are hierarchically. A POI with a street and house number doesn't necessarily has to contain a city, state or country. That's why a simple query will only work for some cases but not for all. A real geocoder however will be able to return a full address for all queries.